# Chat server using Nodejs & Socket.io : Best way to log conversations

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm using a Chat server with multiples rooms using nodejs and socket.io. I was wondering what is the best way to save all conversation ?

I'm also using Mysql and Redis (session). I'm not sure that MySQL is a good choice since it will be overloaded and I need it to display other page contents.
What about flat files ? This coulb be awesome, but isn't there some risk of having the file already opened while trying to save a new message ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I developed a chat called `montreus-chat` with Socket.IO, Node.js and MongoDB.
The full source can be found on [this GitHub repo](http://github.com/gtomitsuka/montreus-chat).

Here's a part of the source that might be helpful:

db.js:

```
var MessageSchema = new Schema({
    message: String,
    room: String,
    sent: Date
});
var Message = mongoose.model('Message', MessageSchema);

var findMessages = function(room) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, decline){
        Message.find({room: room}).sort({sent: 'ascending'}).exec(function(error, messages) {
            if(!error){
                resolve(messages);
            }else{
                console.error(error.message);
                decline(error);
            }
        });
    });
}

var addNewMessage = function(message, room){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, decline){
        var newMessage = new Message({
            message: message,
            room: room,
            sent: new Date()
        });
        newMessage.save(function(error){
            if(!error){
                resolve();
            }else{
                console.error(error);
                decline(error);
            }
        });
    });
}

//Exporting methods
exports.find = findMessages;
exports.add = addNewMessage;
```

app.js:

```
roomRouter.get('/room/:id/', function(req, res){
    var id = req.params.id;
    var roomName;
    var roomId;
    for(var i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++){
      var room = rooms[i];
        if(room.number == id){
            roomName = room.name;
            roomId = room.roomId;
        }
    }
    if(roomName == null){
        res.status(404).sendFile(__dirname + '/error.html');
    }else{
        db.find(roomId).then(function(messages){
            res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.status(200).send(ejs.render(indexEJS, {title: roomName, id: roomId, messages: messages}));
        }, function(error){
            res.status(500).send("Uh oh! An error ocurred: " + error.message);
        });
    }
});
//Inside io.on("connection", ...
socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
            if(!verifyEmptyness(msg.message)){
                var result = processMessage(msg);
                if(result.sendToAll === true){
                    io.in(socket.handshake.query.room).emit('chat message', result.message);
                    db.add(result.message, socket.handshake.query.room);
                }else{
                    socket.emit('chat message', result.message);
                }
            }else{
                var time = moment(msg.date).format("LT, D/M");
                socket.emit('chat message', generateMessage("You may not send empty messages", time, false));
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you ! I'll have a look. I ain't so familiar with NoSQL Databases and was wondering if that can be achieved with Redis? If not, having mysql, redis and MongoDB on the same server could be troubles for CPU and RAM usage ?

Comment: Well, that might be a possible performance problem, depending on your server. If it has enough power, it won't be a problem.

Comment: But, if this is indeed possible with Redis, then I have no clue on how to do it, sorry.